# Excel Function to Find/Identify Duplicates in a given Column (COL A) and Type "Duplicate" in the cell next to it in COL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

could be a simple one, but I need assistance to achieve the following without using VBA.
I have in "Column A" a list of Duplcate and Unique values. My aim is output the words "Duplicate" or "Unique" in the cell next to the record. Thanks.

```
COLUMN A    COLUMN B
ABCD1506825 DUPLICATE
ABCD1506825 DUPLICATE
ABCD1506825 DUPLICATE
ZYXX7508170 DUPLICATE
ZYXX7508170 DUPLICATE
ZYXX7508170 DUPLICATE
CCCC7508966 UNIQUE
DDDD7517119 UNIQUE
```

Comment: Use COUNTIF: `IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,"DUPLICATE","UNIQUE")`

Comment: Thanks BigBen. Appreciate the prompt response to this post. I have used that  function and just changed A1 to read as A2 and it worked as I wanted it to: IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,"DUPLICATE","UNIQUE")

Comment: @Willzai be good to accept BigBen's answer using the check mark top left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNTIF`:

```
IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,"DUPLICATE","UNIQUE")
```